# ssh + sudo + su into login shell

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I have several machines I ssh into regularly only for the purpose of using `sudo su` to spend the rest of my session logged in as some special-purpose user. The general workflow is:

```
mymachine:~ me$ ssh me@othermachine
othermachine:~ me$ sudo su - specialuser # note: no password needed
othermachine:~ specialuser$ # do stuff
```

I'd like to boil this down into a one-liner that I can alias, so I can just set up an alias for each machine and get to where I need to be in a single command, without having to type the `sudo su - specialuser` boilerplate. I could maybe set up `me@othermachine` to `sudo su` on login, but I'd like to keep the flexibility to operate as `me` if I need to.

(**Note:** I don't have any control over `othermachine` or the way it's set up; this is an established workflow that I came in on when I was hired.)

My first thought was just

```
ssh me@othermachine "sudo su - specialuser"
```

and this sort of works, but it gets me no prompt, `^C` kills it and logs me out, and I assume various other things are probably wrong too.

After reading [Run Remote ssh command with Full Login Shell](https://superuser.com/questions/306530/run-remote-ssh-command-with-full-login-shell) I tried a couple of more exotic things like

```
ssh me@othermachine 'bash -l -c "sudo su - specialuser"'
```

and

```
ssh me@othermachine 'bash -l -c "sudo su - specialuser"; bash'
```

-- neither of which I expected to work, and they didn't, but I thought I should try them for completeness (and to avoid close-as-duplicate); they produced the same prompt-less shell (the second with an added bonus prompt-less shell for `me` after `exit`-ing from the one for `specialuser`). And I tried

```
ssh me@othermachine "sudo su - specialuser -c bash -l"
```

but it just got me

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Better ideas?

Comment: What about adding the sudo command to `~/.profile` after a short delay?

Comment: The idea being that in the odd case I don't want to `sudo` I should hit `^C`? If I can't come up with anything better I might try that.

Comment: You could `su me` from `specialuser`. Or in `.profile` or `.bashrc`, if you don't follow the `sudo` with  `exit`, your first `exit` will take you back to `me`, with a second to end the session. Or even use a flag file, so `sudo` is preceded by `[ -f ~/.keep.me ] && del ~/.keep.me` and followed by `[ \! -f ~/.keep.me ] && exit`: you then need only a script or alias for a command `me` as `:>~/.keep.me; exit`. Now `exit` will end your session and `me` will go back to your login session.

Comment: Please consider to write in your final version `/bin/bash` and not a simple `bash` for security reason (to avoid [trojan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29) ). Especially if there is a `sudo` before...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This line should works for you

```
ssh -t me@machine "sudo su - specialuser"
```

This solution give me a prompt or not depending on `-t` switch

```
ssh -t me@machine "/bin/bash -l"   # Give me a prompt

ssh  me@machine "/bin/bash -l"     # Give me NO prompt
ssh  me@machine                    # Give me NO prompt
```

Notes from `man ssh`

> **-t**
>   Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  **Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty**.

Comment: This works for me ... can it be done via host specific ~/.ssh/config setting, too?

Comment: @where, yes you can do that with `RequestTTY force` (which equals `-t`) and `RemoteCommand sudo su - specialuser`! However, be aware that other programs that use SSH (like scp, rsync, etc) will not work properly for this host any more.