# How can you execute files mounted via sshfs?

Tags: linux, mount, file-permissions, fstab, sshfs

This does not work:

```
$ touch testfile
$ chmod 777 testfile
$ ls -l testfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 quinn dialout 0 Apr 18 10:15 testfile
$ ./testfile
-bash: ./testfile: Permission denied
$ sudo ./testfile
sudo: unable to execute ./testfile: Permission denied
```

I am mounting via this line in my fstab:

```
sshfs#127.0.0.1:/remote-dir /data/local-dir fuse port=2222,user,uid=1000,allow_other 0 0
```

note: I am connecting to localhost over port 2222 because I am using a tunnel.

Comment: I updated the example to address your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `exec` option to your fstab line.

From the [ArchWiki page for fstab](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab):

```
exec - Allow execution of binaries on the filesystem.
...
user - Allow any user to mount the filesystem.
       This automatically implies noexec, nosuid, nodev, unless overridden.
```

So you have `user`, but `user` implies `noexec`, so you need to add `exec` to negate that.

Comment: My line is `myuser@mydomain:/home/myuser /home/myotheruser/mymountpoint fuse.sshfs users,_netdev,reconnect,uid=myotheruser,gid=myotheruser,idmap=user,allow_other,exec 0 0` where myuser is a remote host user and myotheruser is local client user.