# Reverse sshfs over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, openssh, sshfs

I want to mount dir on remote machine from host machine connected over ssh preferably via ssh tunnel; with method described below.

[how to mount local directory to remote like sshfs?](https://superuser.com/questions/616182/how-to-mount-local-directory-to-remote-like-sshfs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But if get peer connection reset on remote connection. Any comments?

Thx

Comment: The answer you referenced should work.  Please provide more details such as your command line invocations and exact error message.

Comment: My question may provide you your answer, I'm able to do this but alas, it needs a password atm - https://superuser.com/q/1514325/365525