# Passwordless sshfs mount over reverse-ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, sshfs, reverse-tunnel

I'm trying to mount a host directory onto a remote machine using `reverse-ssh` and `sshfs`

For the most part, running the following command on the host works

`ssh -t -L 0.0.0.0:10000:localhost:10000 -i /home/<local-user>/.docker/machine/machines/aws-sandbox/id_rsa -p 22 <remote-user>@<remote-ip> -R 10000:localhost:22 source /etc/profile;mkdir /home/<remote-user>/test;sudo sshfs -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost=yes -odebug -o allow_other -p 10000 <local-user>@localhost:/home/<local-user>/local/path/to/mount /home/<remote-user>/test`

but no matter what I do I can't seem to get this work without it putting up a password prompt for

`<local-user>@localhost's password:`

If I enter the password at the prompt, the mount is correctly initialized and works as expected. How can I do this in a password-less fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this method to work, but I did using the information from [this](https://blog.dhampir.no/content/reverse-sshfs-mounts-fs-push) excellent article!

Here's my final command that even uses `docker-machine ssh` to eliminate some of the nastiness of passing in ssh auth arguments.

`dpipe /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server = docker-machine ssh <machine-name> sshfs :/host/path/to/mount /remote/path/to/mount/at -o slave`

Note: The `dpipe` command needs the `vde2` package installed on the host to work.