# Having your shell commands run after consecutive ssh

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, shell, zsh

I have a function in my zsh source file `~/.zshrc`:

```
function cr() {
   ssh -p 5022 myname@ssh.mylaboratory.fr
   ssh servername2
   screen -ls
}
```

However, everything after the first ssh seems to be executed after I close the ssh conection while I would like `ssh servername2` to be executed into the `ssh` session. Similarly, the `screen -ls` is not executed inside `servername2` but in my own local terminal after the first ssh closes.

Do you know how I could do that if you please?
Please note that I indeed have a first ssh conection that allows me to connect to my wanted final server, `servername2`. I don't know why they do so in my lab or if it is frequent ^^' I know it is a sort of a gateway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, everything after the first ssh seems to be executed after I close the ssh connexion

That's because functions (and scripts, and aliases) *do not simulate keyboard input.* Each statement is a command that must finish before the next is run, and the entire thing runs in the context of the parent shell.

(This applies regardless of how the commands are separated; whether it's new lines, or `;` or `&&` as separator, they all will be run locally and not sent as "fake keyboard input".)

One way to make this work can be found in older posts – the second `ssh` has to be *given to the first one* as a "remote command":

- [With ssh, how can you run a command on the remote machine WITHOUT EXITING?](https://superuser.com/questions/261617/with-ssh-how-can-you-run-a-command-on-the-remote-machine-without-exiting?rq=1)
- [Run Remote ssh command with Full Login Shell](https://superuser.com/questions/306530/run-remote-ssh-command-with-full-login-shell?rq=1)

In many cases, there is a better option to connect through intermediate hosts using SSH's "tunnel" or "jumphost" support:

```
ssh -J ssh.mylaboratory.fr servername2 "screen -ls"
```

I would also suggest defining SSH parameters in `~/.ssh/config` so that they don't need to be repeated for every SSH or SFTP or sshfs invocation:

```
Host ssh.mylaboratory.fr
    User myname
    Port 5022
```

Or possibly even:

```
Host lab
    Hostname ssh.mylaboratory.fr
    User myname
    Port 5022
```

This would let you simplify the first command to `ssh ssh.mylaboratory.fr` or `ssh lab`, or the "jump" command to `ssh -J lab server2`.

Similarly, if the `ssh -J` option works (i.e. it wasn't explicitly disabled by the remote server), you can define that in the config as well, allowing you to *directly* use `ssh server2` and even `sshfs server2:[...]`:

```
Host server2
    ProxyJump lab
```

Comment: A huge thank you to you, you helped me save a lot of time :)