# Executing a python script via SSH on remote and scp on localhost

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, python, scp

I am new to this and need some advice on resolving my problem.
I have a python script on a remote server. I want to execute that script from my local system and then transfer the result file generated on the remote server to my local system.

So, I would be grateful if someone can help me with a **script or single command** that can do this.

I tried a script but when I am in the remote server via SSH, the second line to execute the python script does not work. I also tried using nohup but still, it is not working

**Below are the steps that need to be followed**

- ssh
- python script.py
- Then 'exit' from ssh
- scp <output_file>

Comment: "I tried a script but when I am in the remote server via SSH, the second line to execute the python script does not work" – Read the beginning of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1704109/432690).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with

```
ssh user@server "python script.py"
scp user@server:/remote/file.txt /local/directory
```

This executes the script on the remote machine, providing you have the proper ip address and filepaths, and will then copy the file from the remote machine to yours.

You could also execute the script using a cron job on the remote machine if you would like to look into it

EDIT: There is no need to actually exit ssh, becuase this ssh command executes the command, but does not establish a running shell, you can test this by running `ssh localhost ls`

Comment: Thank you!
I tried running the first step, I am getting some script related error as below (I already installed netaddr):

    from   netaddr  import IPAddress
ImportError: No module named netaddr

Comment: try logging in and running your script normally

Comment: If I execute the python script by logging in to the server directly, then it is running fine. But when I am trying to execute via my local system using the command you provided, it is giving the same error

Comment: Try creating script on the remote machine with ```#!/bin/bash python script.py``` and execute the script

Comment: I created a test script that worked fine but with my existing script it is throwing the error "No module named netaddr"