# Switch Users and Then send commands

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I am trying to write one-line command which switches user, sends some commands and then displays the result back onto the screen of user1.

Currently, I am writing one-line command like this from the user1's terminal

su - user2; command1; command2; command3;

This command is not working as after switching to user2 the other commands are not executed because they are not parsed to user 2.

Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: Try `su - user2 'command1; command2; command3'` -- check your `su` man page

Comment: Consecutive commands *do not simulate keyboard input*. In `su …; command1; …`, `command1` will be executed in the context of the current shell after `su` exits. It's similar with `ssh …; command1; …`; compare [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1704108/432690). It's similar with `bash; command1`, `python; command1` and many similar constructs.